# m2e plugin - Eclipse - created Java class and package. Not recognized as part of the project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, package, m2eclipse

I installed m2e (1.7) plugin to use maven on eclipse Mars. 
Creating a new maven web-app project, I tried to add a new java class to src/main/resources folder. I simply created an Hello.java class in com.sample package.

As you can see from the image below, the package is not shown as package visualization (It is shown as a folder path to the java class) and
most important, opening the Hello.java class, editing the file with error, eclipse does not point out the error. Even the Hello.java file icon is different.

How I can fix the problem? thank you in advance.

[image: m2e eclipse project]

Comment: Right click the project > Configure > Configure as Maven Project. It will convert the project as Maven project and will add on necessary jar and dependencies. After that Right Click > Maven > Update Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the Java source code should be in **src/main/java** source folder, not in **src/main/resources** like yours.
To fix this:
You should check if the **src/main/java** existed or not. You can do this by expanding the **src/main** folder at the bottom of the above image.

If there is a **java** folder, you **select** and **right click** on the **java** folder --> **Build Path** --> **Use as Source Folder**.

If there is no  **src/main/java**, you can create new one by right click on your project --> **New** --> **Source Folder**. Enter **src/main/java**

Then move your *Hello.java* to that folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just created a java folder under main and everything goes fine!